# bash: git: command not found

Tags: windows-7, bash, git, git-bash

When I attempt to run `git --version` (or any git command) in git-bash, I get the following error:

```
bash: git: command not found
```

In Windows, I have `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` in my Path system variable.

I have created a shortcut on my desktop for git-bash. In its properties, I have removed the `--cd-to-home` flag from the Target executable, and changed the "Start in" directory to one that is a git repository: `D:\my-proj`.

When I open git-bash from this shortcut, `pwd` returns `/d/my-proj` as expected. However, I still get the `bash: git: command not found` issue.

Running `env` from git-bash, I found a couple interesting things:

1. `HOME` and `HOMEDRIVE` are set to `/z/` and `Z:`, respectively.
2. `PATH` is set to `.:/z//bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/X11R5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sas/tools/com`
3. `ORIGINAL_PATH` seems to point to my Windows path variable, but it includes `/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/z/bin`, and does not show a path to Git.

It seems that my git-bash isn't playing nicely with my Windows path variables, but I'm not sure how to set them so I can run Git commands from git-bash. Any advice?

Comment: Do you by any chance have files called `.profile` or `.bashrc` in your home directory?

Comment: @gronostaj My home directory according to git-bash is `/z/`, and in there I have both files. Should I look for anything particular in them?

Comment: @gronostaj Thank you for your comment. I found that my `.profile` was setting the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `.profile` was setting the `PATH` variable, preventing it from recognizing git in the Windows path. Commented out this line and it worked.